# php multi dimensional array's

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I am pulling data out of a table that has these fields:

```
zipcode,city,state,county
```

My question is that some zip codes are in multiple cities, and some cities are in multiple zip codes... so is there a way to have all the data put into an array, then group all of the zip codes in order, then build a table out of that, so that it puts them in order, but if the data is redundant, like the zip, city, state and county are already in the array, then it skips it?

so then I can print it to the browser using echo, into a table like this:

```
74801 | Shawnee, Oklahoma | Pottawatomie
74801 | Bethel, Oklahoma | Pottawatomie
74801 | Johnson, Oklahoma | Pottawatomie
74851 | McLoud, Oklahoma | Pottawatomie
74851 | Dale, Oklahoma | Pottawatomie
```

etc.
But in the case of these:

```
74015 | CATOOSA, Oklahoma | Rogers
74015 | COTOOSA, Oklahoma | Rogers
```

Because those are duplicates in those fields (not in the rest of the table), I need it to skip showing it twice.

I think it is something like this:

```
$zipArray = array();
$zipCode = $dbhhandle->zip;
$cityName = $dbhhandle->city;
$countyName = $dbhhandle->county;
if($zipArray[$zipCode][$cityName] != $countyName) {
   $zipArray[$zipCode][$cityName] = $countyName;
}
```

but I'm not sure if that is the right way to do it.

Then once I have the array built, how do I build the table?

Comment: It's more about your query than about your server-side code; eliminate the duplicates and you won't have to process them there. One possible approach is `SELECT zipcode, city, state, country FROM table GROUP BY zipcode, city, state, country`.

Comment: I cannot eliminate the duplicates, because there are other fields that are unique... but I'm only showing the zip, city, state and county (not country like USA, more like the county the city is in)

Comment: But if you only show these fields, why query for something else?

Comment: Because the query is for people that are looking for a job in their area, I show them which areas are available in their area and pull a 100 Mile Radius from their zip code using lat/long...  but I also use that same table for customers and other things. The data file I got with all the 75k+ records had some records that were identical in the zip,city,state... but other fields where not. I wrote code that went and got the zip code and went to a website and found the county, then updated the county in the database.

So, I don't want to delete any data, in case I delete something unique I need

Comment: I should have de-dupped it before I started using it, but I already passed that road.

Comment: Did I say anything about deleting? It's 'SELECT'.

Comment: This is `data normalization`. Extract those for columns to a separate array and give each one a unique id (city_codes). In the original table, replace those four column with the reference to the `city_codes` array.

Comment: lol, I seen "Eliminate" and in my mind, I replaced that with delete. Sorry :) lol

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks pretty close, but it's missing the state. So change the elements of the array into associative arrays with `state` and `county` elements.

Also, you need to check whether there's an entry for the zip code at all, before checking whether it's a duplicate, otherwise you'll access an undefined index.

```
$zipArray = array();
$zipCode = $dbhhandle->zip;
$cityName = $dbhhandle->city;
$countyName = $dbhhandle->county;
$stateName = $dbhandle->state;
if(!isset($zipArray[$zipCode][$cityName]) || $zipArray[$zipCode][$cityName]['county'] != $countyName) {
   $zipArray[$zipCode][$cityName] = array('county' => $countyName, 'state' => $stateName);
}
```

To display the table, you use nested loops.

```
foreach ($zipArray as $zip => $cities) {
    foreach ($cities as $city => $cityData) {
        echo "<tr><td>$zip</td><td>$city, {$cityData['state']}</td><td>{$cityData['county']}</td></tr>";
    }
}
```